# Take Current Snapshot of DB and send it to FTP in same PHP Scripts: Advice Needed

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

Not sure if I can do it this way. I want to get current snapshot of the database and send it via FTP Server, both of this functionality should be implemented in PHP scripts.

Here are the steps I am thinking on right now.

In my php scripts(basically am extending an PDO into my Dao class and then preparing the query),

```
 $qry = SELECT * FROM MyTablename;
 $stmt = $this->prepare($qry);
 $stmt = $this->execute();
```

Now I will store `$stmt` in csv file using `fputcsv` or I will execute the `sql` command from the script itself and than try to store the result in the `$file(csv file)` note here that I do not have any csv file with me at this point to basically I will have to create one and let's say its `$file`, so then

```
$file = fputcsv($stmt); or $file = exec("Select * from MyTablename");
```

Will this put all records in the file ? If yes, then I will use FTP Functionality to transfer file to the FTP Folder.

I am not sure if this approach would work and also have concerns regarding the need of preparing the `$qry`

Any suggestions or different approach advised would be highly appreciated.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Down voters, please leave comment !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql'); 
mysql_select_db($dbname); 
$list = array(); 
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * from table"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){ 
    $list[] = $row; 
    } 
$fp = fopen("file.csv", 'w+'); 
foreach ($list as $line) { 
    fputcsv ($fp, implode(',', $line)); 
}
```

then try:

```
$conn_id = ftpconnect('host',21);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'user_name', 'user_pass');
ftp_fput($conn_id, 'file.csv', $fp, FTP_ASCII);

ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($fp);
```

I write the code without testing it but should be something like that ;)

good luck.